# Succeeded in Deploying Flask app at Azure, but app does not work upon opening website

Tags: python, azure, flask

I have a problem with deploying my flask application to azure. I am currently deploying it through github, and deployed successfully. But upon opening the website, it gives me errors. Mainly this (looked on Application logs):

> ```
>  2019-11-15T02:22:03.098959319Z /opt/startup/startup.sh: 23:
>   /opt/startup/startup.sh: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout: not found
> ```

and this:

Container goodnewsviagithub_0_a04a1362 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

My entry point is gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 run:app

: [And my code is](https://github.com/AlbertSugi/Work-Management-App)

Is this because of my flask structure?

Any help would be great! I am really stuck on this.

Thank you very much again! Hope you all have a great day.

Comment: Please remove your tokens and secrets from github. What port is it running on server and what port are you trying to access?

Comment: Thanks Srikanth! I have removed the tokens from github. I dont really know, I just deploy it through azure from github. Do you think i need a web.config for azure app deployment? I am really new in this.

Comment: What is your web access url? By default flask app runs on port 5000. If you want different port you should explicitly specify in app.run

Comment: @AlbertSugianto So did you fix your issue? I reviewed your code and try to test your flask structure, I sure that's OK without a specified port writen in `app.run()`, because the `gunicorn` default port is `8000` which be not related to flask default port if you started up the app by gunicorn. But according to your error information and check your `requirements.txt`, it seems that there is `gunicorn` record in the `requirements.txt` if you have not added it manually. So the error means the `gunicorn` command not found, because it had not installed, I think that's the key.

Comment: Hi @PeterPan Thank you very much for your reply. I have followed your suggestion and put gunicorn in my requrements.txt, but still got this error:                                       usage: __main__.py [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME][--noauth_local_webserver] [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]][--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
 __main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo it turns out to be the shebang in python that linux needs to identify the py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
# ^ is the shebang, not a comment 

from flaskapp import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port="8400",debug=True)
    #app.run(host='172.17.0.1',port="3306",debug=True)
```